# Make all word with special character list in each position SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table similar this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
[harfno] INT,
[harf] NCHAR(1) NULL
)
```

and below values row count and harfno is variable

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([harfno],[harf]) VALUES (1,'a')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([harfno],[harf]) VALUES (2,'b')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([harfno],[harf]) VALUES (3,'c')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([harfno],[harf]) VALUES (3,'d')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([harfno],[harf]) VALUES (4,'e')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([harfno],[harf]) VALUES (5,'f')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([harfno],[harf]) VALUES (5,'g')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([harfno],[harf]) VALUES (5,'h')
```

I need output like this: all word  with special character list in each position ,position is harfno in each harfno maybe I have more than on char

```
word
abcef
abceg
abceh
abdef
abdeg
abdeh
```

Comment: What if there is no letter for some position?

Comment: for ecah postion i have at least one char

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naive approach:

```
SELECT t1.harf + t2.harf+ t3.harf+ t4.harf+ t5.harf AS word
FROM Test t1, Test t2, Test t3, Test t4, Test t5
WHERE t1.harfno=1
  AND t2.harfno=2
  AND t3.harfno=3
  AND t4.harfno=4
  AND t5.harfno=5;
```

**[DBFidlde Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=87c348b31a642a3d3e810a02046257e9)**

## EDIT:

Recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte(harf, harfno) AS (
   SELECT CAST(harf AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 1 AS harfno
   FROM Test
   WHERE harfno=1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.harf + t.harf,t.harfno
   FROM Test t
   JOIN cte c
     ON t.harfno = c.harfno+1
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE LEN(harf)= (SELECT MAX(harfno) FROM cte)
ORDER BY harf
--OPTION(MAXRECURSION nn)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0bc68a121838daac4be275a0c1563796)**

Comment: row count and harfno is variable

Comment: @jozi I know that is why I wrote 'naive approach'. Of course you could build dynamic SQL around it.

Comment: Maybe another way can be answered with the solution you've already worked on

Comment: @jozi Working on recursive CTE. Please wait 5 min

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness